# Radio buttons enabled, user cannot change the value

Tags: mfc

Is it possible to have enabled radio buttons though the user cannot change the value?

Comment: ok you are writing mfc. sorry.. are readonly radios not there? I guess you need that.

Comment: No there is no option, and still it will look like disabled (as for edit boxes)

Comment: are disabled radios and hidden inputs there? You can apply the same logic like I answered then.

Comment: The problem is I do not wish to have my radiosdisabled!

Comment: Do you have a really good reason for doing this?  It sounds like a recipe for confusing your users.

Comment: it is in mys specs unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. If you create your radio buttons with the [`BS_RADIOBUTTON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951.aspx#BS_RADIOBUTTON) style instead of [`BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951.aspx#BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON) then Windows will not automatically change the selection when the user clicks a radio button. (In the dialog editor in Visual Studio, right click the radio button and set the **Auto** property to **False**.)

Read the "Using Radio Buttons" section of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775949.aspx) in MSDN for more information.

Answer (score 1):

either you can setchek it to BST_CHECKED and the EnableWindow to FALSE

or..

on every other selection of radio button make the radio button that you need selected